# ComponentDidMount actions with timeout

Tags: scala.js, scalajs-react

I am trying to perform some actions when my component did mount, but not immediately. My component looks like something this:

```
object MyComponent {
  def apply = compopnent()

  class Backend($: BackendScope) {
    def render = {
      // Some markup
    }

    def actions() = setTimeout(1000) {
      //... Some state modifications
    }
  }

  val component = ScalaComponent.builder[Unit]("My component")
  .renderBackend[Backend]
  .componentDidMount(f => f.backend.actions())  // HERE!
  .build
}
```

I get type missmatch. Found SetTimeoutHandle, required react.Callback.

How to use timeout inside componentDidMount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CallbackTo`](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/japgolly/scalajs/react/Callback.scala) class has `async` / `delay` / `delayMs` methods. You can get a delayed state mod callback like so: `$.modState(...).delayMs(1000).void`.

---

Note that async callbacks in React.js need careful handling. 1 second from mounting, your component might already be unmounted (in theory), and if your callback runs when it's already unmounted you will get an error. I'm not sure if scalajs-react offers anything on top of React.js in that regard.

Comment: I was tryed to experiment with `delayMs`. I got type missmatch again at the same place. Found `CallbackTo[Future[Unit]]`, required `CallbackTo[Unit]`. Is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: @Oleg yep, use the `void` method from the same CallbackTo class to discard the Future's value